# error in using concatenate in keras in google colab

Tags: keras, concatenation, google-colaboratory, keras-layer

[image: the_error_i_received]

the error is mentioned in the picture.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-200-8ea67f851d87> in <module>()
      1 final_model = Sequential([
----> 2   Concatenate([image_model, caption_model], mode='concat', concat_axis=1),
      3   Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False)),
      4   Dense(vocab_size),
      5   Activation('softmax')
```

Comment: the error says - mode is not an argument in `Concatenate`...

Comment: Hi ComputerVisionEnthusiast, we can help you better when introduce the problem before the code, and share the error as text instead of a screenshot, [please see the guide on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Concatenate layer wrong. Change your code to the following:

```
final_model = Sequential([
             Concatenate([image_model, caption_model], axis=1),
             Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False))
             Dense(vocab_size), 5 Activation('softmax'),
             Activation('softmax')
])
```